# const array class member initialization

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization

How to init constant integer array class member? I think that in same case classic array isn't best choice, what should I use instead of it?

```
class GameInstance{
    enum Signs{
        NUM_SIGNS = 3;
    };
    const int gameRulesTable[NUM_SIGNS][NUM_SIGNS]; //  how to init it?
public:
    explicit GameInstance():gameRulesTable(){};
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I looked this question, but those question was answered in 2008, and there was some discussion about possible new standart features, which was accepted later in 2011.

Comment: There is an answer for C++11 in that question.

Comment: @vard It's the answer by Flexo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make it static?

```
class GameInstance{
    enum Signs{
        NUM_SIGNS = 3};
    static const int gameRulesTable[2][2];
public:
    explicit GameInstance(){};
};

...in your cpp file you would add:
const int GameInstance::gameRulesTable[2][2] = {{1,2},{3,4}};
```

Comment: Unfortunately my compiler doesn't allow this. He said that there is multiple array declaration.

Comment: @vard 'const int GameInstance::gameRulesTable[2][2] = {{1,2},{3,4}};' - this should be in a .cpp file.

Answer (score 7):

In C++11, you could initialize const array member in an initialization list

```
class Widget {
public:
  Widget(): data {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} {}
private:
  const int data[5];
};
```

or

```
class Widget {
    public:
      Widget(): data ({1, 2, 3, 4, 5}) {}
    private:
      const int data[5];
    };
```

useful link: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1852519

http://allanmcrae.com/2012/06/c11-part-5-initialization/